# problema para obtener id de mongodb

Tags: javascript, nodejs, mongodb

```
const express = require('express')
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt')
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken')
const { expressjwt } = require('express-jwt')
const User = require('./user')


mongoose.connect('mongodb+srv://mbrown:mm080520@cluster0.okaml.mongodb.net/milog?retryWrites=true&w=majority')

const app = express()

app.use(express.json())

const validateJwt = expressjwt({ secret: 'mi-string-secreto', algorithms: ['HS256'] })
const signToken = _id => jwt.sign({ _id }, 'mi-string-secreto' )

app.post('/register', async (req, res) => {
...............}

app.post('/login', async (req, res) => {
...............}

app.get('/lele', validateJwt, async (req, res, next) => {
    try{
        const user = await User.findById(req.user._id)
        if(!user){
            return res.status(401).end()
        }
        req.user = user
        next()
    }catch(e){
        next(e)
    }
}, (req, res) => {
    res.send(req.user)
})

app.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log('Listening in port 3000')
})
```

tengo problema en el 'const user = await User.findById(req.user._id)'
me indica indefinido siendo que en la coleccion se encuentra completp el registro
me pasa al obtener con postman la peticion get en la 'app.lele'

llevo pegado en este error varios dias si alguien me pudiese ayudar pore favor

Comment: La unica que se me ocurre es que estés combinando `strings` con `ObjectId`. Si pones `console.log(req.user)` que sale en la consola? podrías poner como está definido ese `user` en la colección?

Comment: Parece que por ahí va el tema, pongo en la consola req.user y me sale no definido y en la colección el usuario es un string y el ID un objectid y cuando quiero mostrar el ID me sale error tmbn

Comment: Hola, en la documentacion de la librería `express-jwt` indica que para sacar el valor del token desencriptado se encuentra en `req.auth` si no se ha rellenado la opción `requestProperty`. Creo que por eso te aparece `undefined`. Puedes revisarlo? Gracias!

Answer (score 0):

el error es que estas usando req.user

```
const user = await User.findById(req.user._id)
```

express-jwt retorna es auth

debe quedar asi.

```
const user = await User.findById(req.auth._id)
```